# Java KeyListener not responding after switching JPanels

Tags: java, swing, timer, jpanel, keylistener

I got a problem with the KeyListener not responding(due to not gaining focus) when I switch between JPanels.

I have Google'd this and know that to fix this problem I need to use KeyBindings, but I don't like KeyBindings. So I was wondering, is there any other way?

Here is the init code of the JPanel that has an unresponsive KeyListener:

```
    public void init()
{
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocusInWindow();
    requestFocus();
    addMouseListener(new MouseInput());
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseInput());
    addMouseWheelListener(new MouseInput());
    addKeyListener(new KeyInput(p));

    t = new Timer(10, this);
    t.start();
}
```

Feel free to ask for more code samples if you need to!

Comment: _...but I don't like KeyBindings_: What is the issue against using them?

Comment: They're kinda messy(my taste)... And the all the tutorials on how to use them are over-complicated.

Comment: -1 for knowing the recommended approach and insisting on not using it - shrugs, it's your time you are wasting ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hacky solution is to call `requestFocusInWindow()` on the `JPanel` to make sure it has focus for `KeyListener`/`KeyAdapter` this should only be called after the Componnet has been added (though to be sure my component has focus I called it after the `JFrame` is refreshed via `revalidate()` and `repaint()`) for example:

```
public class MyUI {

    //will switch to the gamepanel by removing all components from the frame and adding GamePanel
    public void switchToGamePanel() {
        frame.getContentPane().removeAll();

        GamePanel gp = new GamePanel();//keylistener/keyadapter was added to Jpanel here

        frame.add(gp);//add component. we could call requestFocusInWindow() after this but to be 98%  sure it works lets call after refreshing JFrame

        //refresh JFrame
        frame.pack();
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();

        gp.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

}
class GamePanel extends JPanel { 

      public GamePanel() {
          //initiate Jpanel and Keylistener/adapter
      }

}
```

However you should use Swing `KeyBinding`s (+1 to @Reimeus comment).

Have a read here to get familiar with them:

- [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Now that you have read that lets show another example to help clarify (though Oracle did a good job)

If we wanted to add a `KeyBinding` to a certain `JComponent` i.e `JButton` for <kbd>Esc</kbd> you would do:

```
void addKeyBinding(JComponent jc) {
        jc.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0, false), "esc pressed");
        jc.getActionMap().put("esc pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.out.println("Esc pressed");
            }
        });

        jc.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0, true), "esc released");
        jc.getActionMap().put("esc released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.out.println("Esc released");
            }
        });
}
```

the above method would be called like:

```
JButton b=..;//create an instance of component which is swing

addKeyBinding(b);//add keybinding to the component
```

Please note:

1) You would not need both `KeyBindings`, I just showed how to get different key state and act appropriately using `Keybindings`.

2) This method will add a `Keybinding` which will be activated as long as <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed and the component is in the window which has focus, you can change this by specifying another `InputMap` i.e:

```
jc.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(..);//will only activated when component has focus
```